# while assigning one object to another what happens really, retain or whole copy of object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

```
classA{

    classB objB=[[classB alloc]init];

    objB.hasAnotherRef=self;


 }


classB{

    classA hasAnotherRef;


}
```

From the above what is happening while assigning the classA itself to classB ivar hasAnotherRef?

My question is

classA has classB ,then classB again has classA by 
**objB.hasAnotherRef=self;** this line.

So what is the size of the objects of classA and classB.

I am so confused.

Which is the largest one in size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is that Objective-C objects are always *pointers*. If not for that fact, the size of both structs would be infinite (due to the circular reference). In proper Objective-C, the classes would look something like this:

```
@class classA;
@class classB;

@interface classA {
    classB * objB;
}
@end

@interface classB {
    classA * objA;
}
@end
```

In this case, the size of both classes is the size of one pointer.

Comment: Actually, the size of one pointer plus the size of any superclasses, plus the size of `struct objc_object` which is the 'base' for every class. This last gives every object one more pointer argument, called `isa`, which is a pointer to the object's `Class`.

Comment: @Jim Dovey: Good point. I specifically omitted superclasses to avoid the overhead, but I should have mentioned the `isa` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Using this kind of pseudocode does not help. Use real code that will compile.

Setting instance variables does not in any way change the size of the object. All instances of classA have storage for the address of one object. All instances of classB have storage for the address of one object.

It does not matter what that object is, it can be an array of 1 million strings, it doesn't affect the size of your instance of classA or classB.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear on your question, but *I think* you're asking if objects are copied by value on assignment.  If that's what you're getting it, then the answer to your question is the object doesn't grow in size when it is assigned to another object.  Rather, a pointer to the object is set.

Comment: There's possibly also some confusion in the poster's mind because the dot syntax as in the question is able implicitly to call a setter in Objective-C 2.0, which may in theory do anything whatsoever but in practise will often retain?